# asprintf cause segmentation fault core dump

Tags: c, linux, sockets, stack-overflow, coredump

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h> // tcp headers
#include <netinet/ip.h>  // ip headers
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int random_int(int min, int max)
{
    int k;
    double d;
    d = (double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1);
    k = d * (max - min + 1);
    return min + k;
}
char * get_random_ip()
{
  int octet1 = random_int(0, 255);
  int octet2 = random_int(0, 255);
  int octet3 = random_int(0, 255);
  int octet4 = random_int(0, 255);
  char * string;
  sprintf(string, "%d.%d.%d.%d", octet1, octet2, octet3, octet4);
  return string;
}

int IPv4_verify(char *ip) {
    int a,b,c,d;
    char t;

    if (4 == sscanf(ip,"%d.%d.%d.%d%c",&a,&b,&c,&d,&t)){
        if (0<=a && a<=255
            && 0<=b && b<=255
            && 0<=c && c<=255
            && 0<=d && d<=255){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return -1;
        }
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}


char * atk_target="86.38.217.13";
int atk_port=9000;
void *httpget(){
    printf("1");
//socket part 
    struct sockaddr_in srv_addrr;
    

    int hpsock;

    if (0 > (hpsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))) 
    { 
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("[attack] HTTP socket build failed\n");
#endif
        exit(0);
    } 
       
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("[attack] HTTP socket build seccuss\n");
#endif   



    memset(&srv_addrr, 0, sizeof(srv_addrr));
    printf("1");
    srv_addrr.sin_family         = AF_INET; 
    srv_addrr.sin_port           = htons(atk_port);
    
    srv_addrr.sin_addr.s_addr    = inet_addr(atk_target); 
    
    if (0 > connect(hpsock, (struct sockaddr*)&srv_addrr, sizeof(srv_addrr))) 
    { 
#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("[attack] HTTP connect failed reconnect\n");
#endif
        exit(0);
    }
//end of socket part
    const char *GET_TIME=
        "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        "Host: %s\r\n"
        "Origin:%s\r\n"
        
        "User-Agent:%s\r\n"
        "X-Forwarded-For:%s\r\n"
        
        "\r\n";
        char * http_request ="";
        int get_len = asprintf(&http_request,GET_TIME,atk_target,atk_target,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36",get_random_ip());
    


}
int main(){
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    httpget();
}
```

there is the code, and when i run it i get a core dump error.but If i remove the socket part,it run succeesfully.And i had try to use snprintf sprintf, still geting same error.I had already read other post on stack overflow,i still dont know hwo to solve this
junk languese junk languese junk languese junk languese junk languese junk languese junk languese junk languese junk languese junk languese junk languese junk languese junk languese junk languese junk languese

Comment: What is `get_random_ip` ?

Comment: "....but If i remove the socket part..." hmmm... it's unclear which part you refer to.

Comment: Further, this should be a complete program (with a `main` and all includes) so that it can bee copied and reproduced. Currently there is missing a lot of stuff.

Comment: i paste all code form my program

Comment: `get_random_ip()` has bug. Try to find it yourself for learning.

Comment: Hint: `char * string;` hmmm.... where do you reserve memory??

Answer (score 3):

There is no `asprintf(3)` in the code you've presented. But there's a call to `sprintf(3)` in `get_random_ip()` that contains a bug.

```
char * string;
sprintf(string, "%d.%d.%d.%d", octet1, octet2, octet3, octet4);
```

The above snippet invokes undefined behaviour because the pointer `string` was never initialized and has an indeterminate value.